# How to make bot send message to other servers except the one it's in

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I got this script below, it sends messages to all servers that have a channel called 'Chat-channel' but the problem is as it's meant to send to every channel called 'Chat-channel', the server itself has that channel so the bot sends to the channel that is in the server you sent from as i well which i don't want, any way to solve this?
`(In short: The bot should send message to all servers that have the bot and a channel called 'Chat-channel' but not send to that server the message was sent from even thought it has a channel called 'Chat-channel')`

```
Chnls=[]
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != bot.user:
        for chan in Chnls:
            ch=get(bot.get_all_channels(),id=chan)
            if ch.name=='Chat-channel' and ch.id in Chnls:
                await ch.send(message.content)
```

Comment: Why not get the users in the channel that you will post to, and cross reference that with your bot's user to exclude those channels

Comment: didn't understand that, how would i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You state that you already have the server list you would like to post to. On each server you can (as per documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#server) call `.members` to return an iterable of all the members in that server. In pseudo-code (i.e. this needs to be modified):

```
for server in server_list: # since you already have this list
    for member in server.members: # maybe server.members()??
        if member is my_bot:
            message = False
            break # leave the inner for loop, so message doesn't get overwritten next iteration
        else:
            message = True
    if message: # meaning "if our bot is not in this server"
        await bot.say('Some message') # we will message them in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

Again assuming that you already have the list of channel ids you can use this method to prevent your bot from sending the same message in the channel

```py
chans=[]
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.channel.name == 'chat-chan' and msg.author.bot == False:
        for i in chans:
            if i != msg.channel.id:
                await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id=i),msg.content)

    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```